# c++: initialization list with no default constructor

Tags: c++, initializer-list

If I have a class `A` without default constructor and a class `B`

```
class B {
  private:
    A m_a;

  public:
    B(A a) : m_a(a) {} 
};
```

How is m_a now initialized? 
By the assignment operator of A or by the copy constructor?

Comment: Copy constructor normally I would expect

Comment: You really can't initialize something with assignment. By that time, it's already initialized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the copy constructor, since it's being copy-initialised.

The assignment operator is used for assignment to an existing object, never for initialisation of a new object.